# Problem regarding Raspberry pi 3 B mobi-engine installation

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, dpkg, azure-iot-edge, moby

Whenever I'm trying to install moby-engine it is showing this error. I want to connect raspberry pi to Azure IoT Edge. I am using the documents of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-install-iot-edge-linux. Help me to resolve this problem[image]

Comment: which OS are you running?

Comment: I'm using raspbian os 10

Answer (score 0):

I solved this installing this specific version, before installing mobi engine

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.2
```

I also wrote about the full steps here

https://elbruno.com/2021/01/29/raspberrypi-install-azureiot-a-couple-of-tips-to-make-it-work/

Regards

-Bruno